# Object CRT in VB script

Tags: vbscript, wsh, secure-crt

Trying to debug the scripts for Secure CRT by Vbsedit

```
Function Get_Session_Path()
    Get_Session_Path = crt.session.path
    crt.Dialog.MessageBox("inside Session path" &Get_Session_Path) &chr(13) 
End Function
```

Trying to compile the above code using Vbsedit but getting a error thrown by 'Wscript'

"Object required 'crt' Code 800A01A8 source Microsoft VBScript runtime error"

Am I missing any library or we can not debug Secure CRT VBscript via vbsedit

Answer (score 1):

The SecureCRT API (the crt object) is not externally exposed. Only SecureCRT can access it, so SecureCRT must be used to run the script...

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to use VBSedit with SecureCRT? Or that there's some trick to it?

Comment: So far as I can tell, no way to use VBSEdit directly.  You could build your code in it to make use of the features, but would have to copy the code into a SecureCRT session to be able to run it